# Can Shadow Pokémon be Shiny in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

After defeating a Rocket grunt, you get a chance to catch their left-behind Shadow Pokémon. Some of these (e.g. Poliwag, Dratini) can be Shiny if encountered in the wild, after a raid, by field research, or hatching from an egg. Pikachu with special hats can also be Shiny.

Can Shadow Pokémon be Shiny? If yes, do they have the usual 1:450 Shiny rate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the introduction of Team GO Rocket Leaders, Shadow Pokemon have a chance to be Shiny.  According to Niantic Support's article on [Team GO Rocket Leaders](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&l=en&s=top-articles&f=team-go-rocket-leaders-giovanni):

> Defeating a Leader also allows you to encounter one of their rare Shadow Pokémon, which also has a chance to be a Shiny Pokémon.

Shiny Shadow Pokemon are mentioned specifically from Leaders, not Grunts, which makes sense for the rarity of Shiny Pokemon

Answer (score 18):

At the time of writing, shiny shadow Pokémon do not exist within Pokémon Go. This is confirmed by multiple threads and discussions on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/search/?q=shiny%20shadow&restrict_sr=1.).

When shadow Pokémon first came out, there was a post going around about a shiny shadow Bulbasaur. However, the post ended up being a fake.

Answer (score 2):

[image: things have changed]

This post is old, but I caught this from classic team rocket.